# @ModelAttribute is not working with spring security

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to redirect the entered username on the login page when login fails but in my controller the username of the user retrieved from "@ModelAttribute("user")" is null. When i'm not using spring security this works.

I'm assuming form actually posts to spring security first and then it is redirected to the controller so the information entered is lost between spring security.

How can i retrieve the user without sending it to link parameters?

PS: I tried to create a controller for "/loginFailed" and send it to there if login fails and use method = RequestMethod.POST on that controller.

LoginController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(@ModelAttribute("user") User u, @RequestParam(required = false) String authfailed, String logout,
            String denied, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", u);
        String message = "";
        if (authfailed != null) {
            message = "Invalid username or password, try again !";
        } else if (logout != null) {
            message = "Logged Out successfully, login again to continue !";
        } else if (denied != null) {
            message = "Access denied for this user !";
        }
        model.addAttribute("error", message);
        return "login";
    }
```

---

login.jsp

```
<c:url var="trylogin" value="/j_spring_security_check" ></c:url>
<c:url var="register" value="/register" ></c:url>

<div id="login-box">
    <form:form action="" modelAttribute="user" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> <form:label path="username"> <spring:message text="Username: "/> </form:label> </td>
                <td> <form:input path="username" /> </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <form:label path="password"> <spring:message text="Password: "/> </form:label> </td>
                <td> <form:password path="password" /> </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <input type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Login"/>"
                                    onclick="document.getElementById('user').setAttribute('action', '${trylogin}')"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Register"/>"
                                    onclick="document.getElementById('user').setAttribute('action', '${register}')"/> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="error">${error}</div>
    </c:if>
</div>
```

---

EDIT (Solution):

Thank you @James creating a failureHandler was the way to go but your solution did not quite work properly because it seems like you need "p:defaultFailureUrl" in the failureHandler bean even though i had "authentication-failure-url="/login?authfailed"" inside the form-login

```
<bean id="failureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    p:useForward="true"
    p:defaultFailureUrl="/login"/>
```

And after that i had to add another function for /login with method post because p:defaultFailureUrl="/login?authFailed" would just sent it as /login and the link at the browser stayed as "/j_spring_security_check" i couldn't understand why.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String loginFail(@ModelAttribute("user") User u, @RequestParam(required = false) String authfailed, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("user", u);
    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("error", "Invalid username or password, try again !");
    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an AuthenticationFailureHandler.  For your purposes it should be enough to declare a bean of the Spring SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler class and specify fowarding the request to the destination URL instead of the default redirect behavior in your configuration.  This way your login controller will have access to the original request including the username.

Documentation: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.html

Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.java

```
<bean id="failureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    p:useForward="true"
/>
```

And then in your form-login specification:

```
<security:form-login 
    ...
    authentication-failure-handler-ref="failureHandler"
    ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a wrong way. Controller for login page use only for view this page. For check credential you need to create service, for example:

```
@Service("adminDetailsServiceImpl")
public class AdminDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private SepAdminDao adminDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) {
        SepAdmin admin;

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(login))
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Admin not found!");
        admin = adminDao.findByEmail(login);
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                admin.getEmail(),
                admin.getPassword(),
                getGrantedAuthorities(admin.getRole().getPermissionNames()));
    }

    private static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(String[] roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String role : roles)
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Assign this service with spring (as example i view you my simple configuration for security):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <beans:bean id="roleHierarchy" class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
        <beans:property name="hierarchy">
            <beans:value>
                <!--Admin-->
                PERM_ROOT > PERM_CREATE_ADMINS
                PERM_CREATE_ADMINS > PERM_DELETE_ADMINS
                PERM_DELETE_ADMINS > PERM_EDIT_ADMINS
                PERM_EDIT_ADMINS > PERM_VIEW_ADMINS
                <!--Role-->
                PERM_ROOT > PERM_CREATE_ROLES
                PERM_CREATE_ROLES > PERM_DELETE_ROLES
                PERM_DELETE_ROLES > PERM_EDIT_ROLES
                PERM_EDIT_ROLES > PERM_VIEW_ROLES
            </beans:value>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="expressionHandler"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <beans:property name="roleHierarchy" ref="roleHierarchy"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
                    <beans:property name="expressionHandler" ref="expressionHandler"/>
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="10"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <http pattern="/resources/js/vendor/language" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none"/>
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/403"
          access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <!--Admin-->
        <intercept-url pattern="/dashboard" access="hasRole('PERM_ROOT')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/create_admin" access="hasRole('PERM_CREATE_ADMINS')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/users/*/edit_admin" access="hasRole('PERM_EDIT_ADMINS')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/users/*/view_admin" access="hasRole('PERM_VIEW_ADMINS')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/users/*/delete_admin" access="hasRole('PERM_DELETE_ADMINS')"/>
        <!--Role-->
        <intercept-url pattern="/role/create_role" access="hasRole('PERM_CREATE_ROLES')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/role/*/edit_role" access="hasRole('PERM_EDIT_ROLES')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/role/*/view_role" access="hasRole('PERM_VIEW_ROLES')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/role/*/delete_role" access="hasRole('PERM_DELETE_ROLES')"/>
        <!--Route-->
        <form-login username-parameter="email"
                    password-parameter="password"
                    login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/login?failed"/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login"/>
    </http>
    <authentication-manager alias="authManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="adminDetailsServiceImpl">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

And then when user submit login form, we redirect to /j_spring_security_check where used our service and if we have an login exception we can check it at login jsp page:

```
<!-- spring_exception -->
<c:if test="${not empty SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION}">
    <p class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
        <spring:message code="Error.Msg.Login"/>
    </p>
    <br/>
</c:if>
```

If it's success, we redirected to default target url, in my case - to root.

```
 <form-login username-parameter="email"
         password-parameter="password"
         login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/login?failed"/>
```

That's why the link at the browser stayed as "/j_spring_security_check".